# ComboBox ValueMember Error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, error-handling

I get this error in my WinForm Application:
**Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().**

This is my code:

```
private DataBaseEntities entity = new DataBaseEntities();
categoryComboBox.DataSource = entity.TableName;
categoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "Description";
//ProductType is the Primary Key of the table and is Identity as well
//And when the compiler arrives here, the error is thrown
categoryComboBox.ValueMember = "ProductType";
```

Can somebody help me to fix my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly assign the Table to grid like that. Try converting it to list like this

```
categoryComboBox.DataSource = entity.TableName.ToList();
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks man. It's working. I've read an article about this error , but there was another case. Thanks again @ElectricRouge .